# Property 'logEvent' does not exist on type 'FirebaseMessaging'

Tags: ionic4

FirebaseMessaging in ionic 4 for connect firebase notification

```
this.firebaseMessaging.onMessage('page_view', {page: "dashboard"})
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));


this.firebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage('page_view', {page: "dashboard"})
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Connect firebase  onBackgroundMessage.
 to get event like wtsap call notification

Blockquote

Comment: What's the question? I think you have a typo, it just says "Blockquote", did you mean to paste something?